# ReactJS - Unable to run babel code without serving HTTP files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, browserify, babeljs

I am new to `reactjs` and trying to install `babel` to run `babel code` without serving HTTP file. By following the [Package Manager](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/package-management.html) I have installed it with `browserify` as:

```
$ npm install --save react react-dom babelify babel-preset-react
$ browserify -t [ babelify ] main.js -o bundle.js
```

After it I created the file `.babelrc` in the same root directory with following code

```
{ "presets": ["react"] }
```

And removed the HTTP `babel-core` source file as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <script src="build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="build/react-dom.js"></script>
    <!-- removed https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('content')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but when I access it from `http://localhost/react/` this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included the code that's failing or the error message, so this is a guess.

The problem is that when you run `browserify`, it transpiles (converts) the code you specify from ES2015 to plain old Javascript. So, when you do this:

```
browserify -t [ babelify ] main.js -o bundle.js
```

You're converting the code in `main.js` and writing it to `bundle.js`.

So there are two problems with your code:

1. you never include `bundle.js` in your HTML file. You need to add `<script src="build/bundle.js"></script>` to load the code that you transpiled.
2. the code in your HTML `<script>` block is not touched by `browserify`. Your build step (running `browserify`) is working on scripts, not on HTML files. So that code never gets transpiled and fails when the browser tries to execute it.

The reason it works when you include `babel-core` in the HTML is because Babel has a special "live" transpilation mode which will transpile your code when the page is loaded, and this mode DOES get the code in the `<script>` block because it's all running on the user's browser.

Comment: so you mean I should include the file `bundle.js` and place the `babel script` in `main.js` in order to run `babel code` without serving HTTP file?